# HashTable efficiency in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, performance, hashtable

I'm writing a J2ME class which reads variable keys and contents from a resource file (as strings). I would like to store those data in something like a HashTable for faster access, so the application won't have to read the file every time it's asked for a key's value.
Should I prefer using the builtin `java.util.Hashtable` or would it be faster or more memory efficient to search the key string every time (e.g. with `foo.indexOf("bar")` in the string that has been read from the file?

Comment: "would it be faster or more memory efficient"  You can't have both.  HashTable is faster.  TreeMap will be more memory efficient.

Comment: In his defense he did use "or" and not "and".  To the OP remember to optimize for readability before all else... I'm sure we all know the badness that is premature optimization.

Comment: @S.Lott: actually, most of the time it's Hashtable/HashMap which is more memory efficient (or rather, less memory inefficient). Those tree nodes have a pretty big overhead.

Comment: If anyone is interested in the result...: [project svn](http://j2me-i18n.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/j2me-i18n/trunk/i18n.java?view=markup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A HashTable is designed for efficient lookups based on arbitrary keys. Yes, it will probably be better than searching in a string for the key every time.

But as with all performance-related questions, the best answer is to **benchmark it yourself**. If an optimization isn't worth benchmarking, it's not an optimization worth making.

Comment: That's true. However be aware that many JavaME implementations use native implementation that may vary from phone to phone/device (even from the same vendor), hence may have different performance.